# Can I invoke a function within a promise chain in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I have a piece of code that I have to work in, I am looking into the promise chain and am wondering if this is correct

```
function1ThatReturnsAPromise(arg1, arg2)
.then(function2ThatReturnsAPromise(arg1, arg2))
.then(function3ThatReturnsAPromise(arg1, arg2))
.catch(functionThatCatchsAError(arg1, arg2));
```

So the question is can I pass in a function that is invoked rather that used as a callback

Note all the args are normally a service that the function uses to perform some task.

I just think you need to pass a function used as a callback but I am not sure.

Comment: If your promises are wrapping asychronous functions and each processing step does not need data from the previous step, chaining your promises might not be a good solution after all. In that case, try `.spread()` or `.map()`.

Comment: Yes, you always need to pass a callback *function* to `then`.

Comment: `functionThatReturnsAPromise` sounds like it will return the wrong thing ... it should be `functionThatReturnsAfunctionThatReturnsAPromiseOrAValue`

Comment: note that the code you have would invoke `function2`,`3` and the `functionThatCatches` immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but like this:

```
function1ThatReturnsAPromise(arg1, arg2)
  .then(function(){
    return function2ThatReturnsAPromise(arg1, arg2)
   })
  .then....
```

Comment: `.then(function(){
    return function2ThatReturnsAPromise(arg1, arg2)
   })` can also be `.then(function2ThatReturnsAPromise.bind(null,arg1, arg2))`